# Cannot retrieve xml attributes in kony

Tags: xml, xpath, temenos-quantum

I am parsing a web-service in kony and it gives me the result in the following format:

```
 <?xml-stylesheet href="/v1/xsl/xml_pretty_printer.xsl" type="text/xsl"?><products canonicalUrl="/v1/products(search=&quot;hdmi&quot;)?apiKey=przdaw9nuqfefhavq3ud4tfh" currentPage="1" from="1" partial="false" queryTime="0.005" to="10" total="2241" totalPages="225" totalTime="0.087">
       <product>
          .....
          .....
       </product>
       <product>
          .....
          .....
       </product>
       <product>
          .....
          .....
       </product>
       <product>
          .....
          .....
       </product>
    </products>
```

I configured the output parameter as giving the root of Xpath as **//products** and to fetch a particular item from product say name,I used **product/name**.The response is coming perfectly.

Now I want to fetch root level elements such as **currentPage="1"** and **totalPages="225"** for the purpose of pagination and I cannot do that.

What I have done:[image]

But unfortunately,in this way I cannot access the **currentPage** attribute.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your screenshot you apparently try to do

```
//products[/currentPage]
```

This is is best described as a shot in the dark in the hopes to hit something. Please take a few moments to learn about the basics of XPath and about the structure of the DOM.

```
/products/@currentPage
```

(Alternatively just `@currentPage` in the collection `pdetails`, which amounts to the same thing.)

Comment: Thanks.It works.Yes I have very limited idea about xml parsing as I did most of my projects in JSON.Indeed it was a shot in the dark.Thank you again.

Comment: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath or http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html are tools to test XPath expressions interactively.